# How do I make a main thread sleep while waiting on some background process to finish?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I am in a situation where I have a main request, but I am waiting on the completion of other requests that were sent in the background. I am trying the following

myclass.rb

```
# class variables
@@semaphore = Mutex.new
# class methods ...
def entry ...
def main_request ...
def background_request ...
```

/entry

```
$unavailable = true
# starts /main_request and /background_request
```

/main_request

```
@@semaphore.synchronize{
    while($unavailable)
        sleep(1)
    end
}
# use information updated by background_request
```

/background_request

```
@@semaphore.synchronize{
    $unavailable = false
}
```

I might have to get more familiar with threads/Mutexes in ruby, or just concurrency in general, since I am already making many assumptions.

The result of this is that the main_request is kept from completing.
I tried it without the semaphore and the main request just seems to die off. (NGINX 499) **In summary, how do I make a main thread sleep while waiting on some background process to finish?**

Maybe I am going about it all wrong. Any suggestions? Can I somehow join different requests/threads somehow?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Updated title and added a key question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but you did know that Thread has an instance method called `join`, right? `foo_thread.join` causes the main thread to wait until `foo_thread` completes its work and returns control to the main thread. This said, you might want to go into more detail about what, exactly, you're trying to achieve because there might be a better way to do it without messing with concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `join` method.
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Thread.html#method-i-join

Just save a pointer to the threads when you create them into a variable (eg. `x = Thread.new`) and when you are ready to wait for them to finish before continuing execution run `x.join`.

Comment: The problem I see with this is that I don't see where I can use the `Thread.new`. I have three REST endpoints that are being called in some unknown order from outside the application, and I am looking to update application state once one of those endpoints finishes it's execution. I will just try preserving in the DB for now probably.